# How to require a licence for running my web application on a different server?

Tags: wordpress, api, frameworks, share

I'm working on my own CMS, a kind of Wordpress 2.0 where I'll be able to create websites very easily for my clients. I'm planning on sharing it someday, no cost included.

The advantages are: People who use my platform won't need any coding skills, and developers will be able to add their code, whether it is PHP, CSS or whatever.

Well, it is just the start. The thing is, I don't know how I'm going to share this framework. The user just needs a bunch of files and a database. The files then setup everything in the database, and we're good to go. The user can create his website without spending a cent.

If I want the user to have a licence to use it, how should I do ? I mean, I think I want it to be free, but at least I want the user to create an account on the official website. How can I forbide the user to "use" the framework if he hasn't an account on the framework's official website?

Thank you for your help,

Stefan

Comment: I think a good way to go is to distribute an installation file which installs the framework and then during the installation process make it easy for them to create an account on the official site. The process would be pretty seamless as they'd have to enter things like database information in the installation too. So just adding two or three more fields somewhere down the installation process, I think most users would take the extra minute to register and complete the installation they already began.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea :)

Comment: I have tried to reword your question, because you target mainly the licence part ... if I didn't get it completely, feel free to change it again.

Comment: Do you know how I can safely access my database from the user's website ?

Comment: Use cURL to ping a script on your server via PHP. Don't actually hand out database credentials for your database. Record the ip address on the account creation request which gets written to your database to prevent abuse. Google's recaptcha checkbox is rather painless to include in any account creation request. Google also has an "invisible" captcha in beta mode which you can try out, but the idea remains the same.